# Posting photo on Facebook wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a photo on a facebook wall. I am using Object Graph API, but this is not working successfully.

```
 if ([PostType isEqual:@"photoalbum"])
        {
        NSString  *imgstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",imgURL,[jsonResponse valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
        NSURL *url   = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage  *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
            NSString*postlink =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[jsonResponse valueForKey:@"postLink"]];


        [dict setObject:PostTitle forKey:@"message"];
        [dict setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
        [dict setObject:postlink forKey:@"postLink"];


            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection ,id result ,NSError *error){
                if(!error){
                    NSLog(@"successfull");
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"unsuccess");
                }
            }];





        }
```

What is wrong with this code. Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: have you set permissions to publish "publish_stream" ? and can you share your error which you ll get while posting image on Facebook...

Comment: yes i set this permission. error is something like this  "code = 200;
            message = "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions";
            type = OAuthException;"